# Is there a way to generate table aliases in TSQL statements using SQL snippets in Azure Data Studio?

Tags: code-snippets, azure-data-studio

In a user snippets the following work,

```
SELECT * FROM ${1:TableName} as ${2|a,b,c,d,e,f|}
```

but it only presents you with a list of the 6 letters ( a to f) for an alias like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Currency as a
```

I want the snippet to use the first 4 characters of the table name as an alias:

```
SELECT * FROM Currency as curr
```

Is there a way to make this happen in a user snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create user snippet to generate first four letters of table name as table name alias as follows:

Add below snippet to the created user snippet:

```
{
    "Create Select Statement": {
        "prefix": "sqlselect",
        "body": [
            "SELECT * FROM ${1:TableName} as ${1/(.{4}).*/$1/}"
        ],
        "description": "Create a SELECT statement for a table"
    }
}
```

In this snippet, `${1/(.{4}).*/$1/}` is using a regular expression transform to capture the first 4 characters of the table name and apply them as the alias. The expression works as follows:

- `(.{4})`: This captures the first 4 characters of the table name.
- `.*`: This matches any remaining characters in the table name.
- `$1`: This references the captured group from the first part of the expression, which are the first 4 characters of the table name.

I formatted above snippet as document and opened new query tab typed `sqlselect` and pressed tab I got below script:

```
SELECT  *  FROM TableName as TableName
```

Entered the table name and pressed tab I got required output as mentioned below:

```
SELECT  *  FROM student as stud
```

[image]

Comment: Nice one, thank you! Additionally, I wanted to make the alias lowercase, and use this:" SELECT * FROM ${1:TableName} as ${1/(.{3}).*/${1:/downcase}/}